# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: iphone

I am working with coredata..I have taken a  navigation based app with coredata option checked..so in my first page will be a default tableview controller ,I addded an add button which opens another table view and i called it "anothertableviewcpntroller"
the code which I wrote to on a add barbutton is below

```
- (void)insertNewObject {
     DetailsTable *details = [[DetailsTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsTable" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: details];
     [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
     [details release];
}
```

Then it opens the table view which,I have populated it with some dummy names ,and when I click on the first cell it opens one more view called `detailviewcontroller`,
the code written on click of cells is below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil]    
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        AddRecipeViewController *addRecipeView = [[AddRecipeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddRecipeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        Recipes *recipes = (Recipes *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recipes" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            addRecipeView.recipes = recipes;    
             UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: addRecipeView];
             [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
             [addRecipeView release];        
 }
}
```

Here I have a text field where the user will add his name and click on save button,

The code for save button is below

```
- (void)save {
     recipes.recipeName = textFieldOne.text;
     recipes.cookingTime = textFieldTwo.text;
     NSLog(recipes.recipeName);
     NSError *error = nil;   
     if (![recipes.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
          // Handle error
          NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
          exit(-1);  // Fail
     }
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When he clicks on save button,the data should appear on the firstpage tableview controller,but its not happening I am getting the above error..i.e

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Recipes''

Can someone help me out.

Comment: I'm going to make a wild stab that maybe an object that is a subclass of NSManagedObjectModel could not locate an entity named "Recipes".  Only you know where/how you've subclassed NSManagedObjectModel, and where/how you specified the entity name "Recipes".

Comment: can i know why that error appears..i am new to it..

Comment: hi daniel shall is send u my project?

Comment: I think you shall figure out your own code.  You apparently have some instance/subclass of NSManagedObjectContext in self.managedObjectContext.  Look for where you set that, and where it's referenced.  If you're a novice one likely error is that you create that object more than once, and overwrite the version that contains the "Recipes" entity you're creating in the above code.  (You also might want to learn how to use the debugger.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your data model in Xcode. You probably meant **Recipe**, not **Recipes**. The name you put in to `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:` must be *exactly* the name in your model.

Comment: thanks morgan for your reply..i checked the names and it is Recipes only and not Recipe

Comment: actually the problem is diffrent,i think the problem is with is managedobjectcontext.......